# How to control when browser prompts for client certificates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, client-certificates

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that accepts client certificate authentication or username/password authentication.

I have set SslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" so the user can decline and proceed to enter their credentials.

[image]

The problem is as soon as they hit the login page they are asked for their client certificate. I am not sure what is designating when they get solicited for it. I don't have a [RequireHttps] for the logon get request in the controller.

How can I delay the modal dialog for the client cert info until they click the smart card (in this case "CAC card") button?

Would really like to avoid setting up 2 separate sites.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you but have recently delved into this "wonderful" feature and have wondered the same thing many times. I'd like to at also remove Request.ClientCertificate for a logout scenario but that appears to be impossible as well.